# Trying to dynamically unpack data - python

Tags: python

i am trying to unpack data i receive from a packet dynamically, the main reason for this is i do not know the length of the ip addresses or the number of ip addresses in a packet, so need to unpack all

```
if our_or_addr_len == 4:
    our_op_ip = struct.unpack(">BBBB", payload[6:10])
    num_their_ips = struct.unpack(">B", payload[10])[0]
    len_their_ips = struct.unpack(">B", payload[12])[0]
    # Much better way to unpack the packet, does unpacking dynamically rather than set values 
    byte_string = '>{}'.format('b'*len_their_ips)
    their_ips = []
    for count in range(num_their_ips):
      start = 13 + (count*len_their_ips)
      end = start + len_their_ips
      ip = struct.unpack(byte_string, payload[start:end])
        print 'IP #{}: {}'.format(count+1, ip)
    their_ips.append(ip)

return { 'tm': tm, 'our_or_ip_version': our_or_ip_version, 'our_or_addr_len': our_or_addr_len, 'our_op_ip': our_op_ip, 'num_their_ips': num_their_ips, 'len_their_ips': len_their_ips, 'their_ips': their_ips }
```

above is currently my code

what it should do is if my ip address is that of an ip v4 for, the for all of their ip address to unpack them for the packet starting at 13 in the payload for the length of their ip address for the number of ip addresses contained

currently it is only outputting one ip address although there is 2 ip address in the payload

shown in this output

```
{'our_or_addr_len': 4, 'len_their_ips': 4, 'our_op_ip': (00, 00, 00, 00), 'their_ips': [(0, 00, 00, 0)], 'tm': 1402265584, 'our_or_ip_version': 4, 'num_their_ips': 2}
```

how can i get both of the ip addresses returned, is there an issue with the loop as i think it should work so am confused as to why only one ip is returned

Answer (score -1):

Managed to fix it it seemed my indenting was out on the `their_ips.append(ip)`  so it was not getting assigned properly, weird how i had no errors however on complie, anyone got a good IDE program for linux and python ?

Comment: Don't ask a new question in your answer. Requests for e.g. IDE recommendations are off-topic here; try [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/search?q=IDE+python+Linux).

Comment: Oh, and no IDE would identify that as an error - it's perfectly valid code, it just didn't do what you wanted. White space is important in Python, I (and PEP-0008) would recommend you consistently use four spaces per level so you can easily see where blocks start and end.